# When I add images to my blogger using External Source it never Appear as Thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html, xml, blogger

Code Copied from my Blogger theme.
I tried by Changing this function. But it never works.

```
<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'> 
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
        
</b:if>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function TSp_thumbnail_resize(image_url,post_title)
{
var image_size=125;
var width_size=65;
var height_size=97;
var show_default_thumbnail=true;
var default_thumbnail="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-erTXCq61ULM/TmHYAQBZ0GI/AAAAAAAACCs/6cBX54Dn6Gs/s72-c/default.png";

if(show_default_thumbnail == true && image_url == "") image_url= default_thumbnail;
image_tag='<div class="post-anime"><img src="'+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/s'+image_size)+'" class="postthumb1" alt="'+post_title+'" width="'+width_size+'" height="'+height_size+'"/></div>';
if(image_url!="") return image_tag; else return "";
}
//]]>
</script>
</b:if>
   
<div class='entrybody'>
<a expr:href='data:post.url'>
<span class='main-overlay'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.write(TSp_thumbnail_resize(&quot;<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>&quot;,&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;));
</script></a></div></b:if></b:if>

    <a expr:name='data:post.id'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:post.title'>
      <h2 class='post-title entry-title' itemprop='headline'>
     <b:if cond='data:post.link'>
       <a expr:href='data:post.link'><data:post.title/></a>
     <b:else/>
        <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
          <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
        <b:else/>
          <data:post.title/>
        </b:if>
     </b:if>
      </h2>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
</b:if>
```

How can I make those external images appear on those thumbnails??
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the default thumbnail generator `<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>`

instead use this one, it will fetch the very first image in the post.

`<data:post.firstImageUrl/>`